"Error decoding scan arguments" capacitor barcode scanner on ios
I am running into this error on IOS (android works totally fine), anyone know a solution for this:
⚡️ To Native -> CapacitorBarcodeScanner scanBarcode 47961097
ERROR MESSAGE: {"errorMessage":"Error decoding scan arguments","message":"Error decoding scan arguments"}
⚡️ [error] - {"errorMessage":"Error decoding scan arguments","message":"Error decoding scan arguments"}
⚡️ [error] - ERROR
CapacitorBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode({hint: CapacitorBarcodeScannerTypeHintALLOption.ALL}).then(({ScanResult}: CapacitorBarcodeScannerScanResult) => { console.log('ScanResult', ScanResult) })
